# Issues with handling union vs intersection Typescript

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, static-typing, union-types

I'm trying to build out an interface with a couple methods, then calling those methods based on an incoming piece of data being one of the keys of that object.

Here is my type:

```js
type LogicalFunction<T> = (args: T) => string;

export interface LogicalFunctions
  extends Record<string, (args: QueryObject & QueryObject[]) => string> {
  $not: LogicalFunction<QueryObject>;
  $and: LogicalFunction<QueryObject[]>;
  $or: LogicalFunction<QueryObject[]>;
}
```

And here is the object that I'm using:

```js
export const logicalFunctions: LogicalFunctions = {
  $not: (expression: QueryObject) => `NOT(${queryBuilder(expression)})`,
  $and: (args: QueryObject[]) => `AND(${queryBuilder(args)})`,
  $or: (args: QueryObject[]) => `OR(${queryBuilder(args)})`,
};
```

And finally, where I am actually calling the function:

```js
if (
  key in logicalFunctions 
  && (isQueryObject(val) || (val instanceof Array && val.every(v => isQueryObject(v))))
) { logicalFunctions[key](val); }
```

But as I have it written, I get the following error from the Typescript compiler:

`Argument of type 'QueryObject | QueryObject[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryObject & QueryObject[]'`

I'm not sure if I have just written this with some sort of anti-pattern, or if I am just missing something. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example. I have tried reproducing it unsuccessfully here: https://tsplay.dev/8w8O4W . You can edit this and help illustrate the issue. Meanwhile, I think you should use `(args: QueryObject | QueryObject[]) => string` this instead

Answer (score 1):

`QueryObject & QueryObject[]` means the argument must both a `QueryObject` and an array of `QueryObjects` at the same time.  Quite likely that is not possible.

`QueryObject | QueryObject[]` means the argument is either a `QueryObject` or an array of `QueryObjects`.  That's probably what you want.

In this example [viewable in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQKALgngDgpsAqwC8wB2BXAtgIxgJ2AB8EBtAXRAGMB7VAZzGDAAYAueAMnnOWBICYywYQHoRwAPIBpKrQZMAjOy48U-YRrHAAcgHEQ4aHACqvDDnyz6jdG2MdjqvoM3i9V+eiX3HQtRtE3fQ8bW1ZjQl9eASFAyRkaa2B0L3DIp3UArWkQIA):

```
type T = number | T[]
const t0:T&T[] = [2]   // OK
const t1:T&T[] = 2     // NG

type U = number
const u0:U&U[] = [2]   // NG
const u1:U&U[] = 2     // NG

const uu0:U|U[] = [2]   // OK
const uu1:U|U[] = 2     // OK
```

variable `t0` is both a `T` and `T[]` (array of `T`) - just to show you that such a thing is possible.  `t1`, `u0`, and `u1` are all compile errors.

However, `uu0` and `uu1` are OK.